# Overwrite a static method with a non static method

Tags: php

I want to overwrite a static method with a non static method. I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot make static method Person::say() non static in class Coder on line 22
```

I want to overwrite a classes parent static method `makeCall()` with a more specific `makeCall()` that would be non-static.

Code:

```
<?php

class Request {

    public static function makeCall($url) {

        // Do some cURL stuff...

    }
}

class API extends Request {

    const PRODUCTS = '/products';

    private $api;

    public function __construct($api) {

        $this->api = $api;
    }

    public function getProducts() {

        $this->makeCall(self::PRODUCTS);
    }

    public function makeCall($service) {

        parent::makeCall($this->api . $service);
    } 
}
```

I could make the parent `makeCall()` non-static, but I also want to be able to `Request:makeCall()` in some places.

Comment: rename it? there's no other option.

Comment: you cant do that as the error is telling you. you will need to use a different method name.

Comment: Oh, so I just need to make `public function fooMakeCall()`. @bwoebi

Comment: yep, and then use $api->fooMakeCall(); ... that's all.

Comment: Thanks @bwoebi! If you'd like the reputation points, put this in answer form and I mark the question answered.

Comment: @jared_flack sometimes I only want to give a hint / a suggestion and I answer unexpectedly the question...^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply change your methods name. And call it with the new name.

There is no option to have it the same name as a static method of the class you're extending.